# Using an if else statement inside a for statement inside lambda statement

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, lambda

So i know that this work :

```
fac = lambda x: [element for element in x]
```

and this also work :

```
fac = lambda x: x*fac(x-1) if x!=0 else 1
```

but why this is not working :

```
fac = lambda *x :  [ n * fac(n-1) if n!=0 else 1 for n in x]
```

i have an infinite loop.

Comment: When I run the last example on its own there is no infinite loop. How are you calling `fac` in the last example?

Comment: @mkrieger1 fac(1, 2, 3) gave me an infinite loop. But I do not understand what was the goal

Comment: @mkrieger1 the goal is caluclating the factorial in one line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`n * fac(n-1)` creates the following list if input is `3`:-

```
[[[[1], [1]], [[1], [1]], [[1], [1]]]]
```

You need to take the first element from the list and multiply it with `n`:-

```
fac = lambda *x :  [ n * fac(n-1)[0] if n!=0 else 1 for n in x]
print(fac(3))
```

Output-

```
[6]
```